# TensorFlow training gets slower every batch

Tags: performance, optimization, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I am new to TensorFlow and I get my code running successfully by modifying tutorials from the official website.

I checked some other answers on StackOverflow, which says my problem is likely due to something is being added to the graph every time. However, I have no idea where to look for the code that might have caused this.

Also, I used tf.py_function to map the dataset because I really need to enable eagerly mode in the mapping.

```
def get_dataset(data_index):
    # data_index is a Pandas Dataframe that contains image/label pair info, each row is one pair
    data_index = prepare_data_index(data_index)
    # shuffle dataframe here because dataset.shuffle is taking very long time.
    data_index = data_index.sample(data_index.shape[0])

    path = path_to_img_dir

    # list of dataframe indices indicating rows that are going to be included in the dataset for training. 
    indices_ls = ['{}_L'.format(x) for x in list(data_index.index)] + ['{}_R'.format(x) for x in list(data_index.index)]
  
    # around 310k images
    image_count = len(indices_ls)

    list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(indices_ls)
    # dataset.shuffle is commented out because it takes too much time
    # list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

    val_size = int(image_count * 0.2)
    train_ds = list_ds.skip(val_size)
    val_ds = list_ds.take(val_size)

    def get_label(index):
        index = str(np.array(index).astype(str))
        delim = index.split('_')
        state = delim[1]
        index = int(delim[0])

        if state == 'R':
            label = data_index.loc[index][right_labels].to_numpy().flatten()
        elif state == 'L':
            label = data_index.loc[index][left_labels].to_numpy().flatten()

        return tf.convert_to_tensor(label , dtype=tf.float16)

    def get_img(index):
        index = str(np.array(index).astype(str))
        delim = index.split('_')
        state = delim[1]
        index = int(delim[0])

        file_path = '{}_{}.jpg'.format(data_index.loc[index, 'sub_folder'],
                                   str(int(data_index.loc[index, 'img_index'])).zfill(4)
                                   )
        img = tf.io.read_file(os.path.join(path, file_path))
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
        full_width = 320
        img = tf.image.resize(img, [height, full_width])

        # Crop half of the image depending on the state
        if state == 'R':
            
            img = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(img, offset_height=0, offset_width=0, target_height=height,
                                            target_width=int(full_width / 2))
            img = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
        elif state == 'L':
            
            img = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(img, offset_height=0, offset_width=int(full_width / 2), target_height=height,
                                            target_width=int(full_width / 2))
        img = tf.image.resize(img, [height, width])
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        img.numpy(), data_format=None, scale=True, dtype=None
    )
        # Apply auto white balancing, output an np array
        img = AWB(img)
        img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype=tf.float16)

        return img

    def process_path(index):
        label = get_label(index)
        img = get_img(index)
        return img, label

    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

    train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(
    process_path,
    [x], (tf.float16, tf.float16)), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(
    process_path,
    [x], (tf.float16, tf.float16)), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

    def configure_for_performance(ds):
        ds = ds.cache()
        # ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=image_count)
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
        ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
        return ds

    train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
    val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)

    return train_ds, val_ds
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Here is the rest of my code.

```
def initialize_model():
    IMG_SIZE = (height, width)

    preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input

    IMG_SHAPE = IMG_SIZE + (3,)
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                         include_top=False,
                                         weights='imagenet')

    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(class_num, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, use_bias=True)

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(height, width, 3))
    x = preprocess_input(inputs)
    x = base_model(x, training=True)
    x = global_average_layer(x)
    outputs = prediction_layer(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    def custom_loss(y_gt, y_pred):
        
        L1_loss_out = tf.math.abs(tf.math.subtract(y_gt, y_pred))
        scaler = tf.pow(50.0, y_gt)
        scaled_loss = tf.math.multiply(L1_loss_out, scaler)
        scaled_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(
            scaled_loss, axis=None, keepdims=False, name=None
        )
        return scaled_loss

    base_learning_rate = 0.001
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=base_learning_rate, momentum=0.9),
                  loss=custom_loss,
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error']
                  )

    return model


def train(data_index, epoch_num, save_path):
    train_dataset, validation_dataset = get_dataset(data_index)
    model = initialize_model()
    model.summary()

    history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                        epochs=epoch_num,
                        validation_data=validation_dataset)
    model.save_weights(save_path)

    return model, history
```

Comment: Can you share your code for `get_dataset` also? You said you decorated it with `tf.py_function`, and my intuition is that the problem is there. Your code here seems fine.

Comment: @FalconUA Thank you for checking my code! I just uploaded the get_dataset. The reason I need to use the eagerly mode in mapping dataset is that I actually want to create two samples out of each of my image, one for left half and the other for the right half. Each side will have its own labels. Therefore I needed to delim the string and convert it to intgers and strings from a Tensor.